# Enabling bitmap fonts selectively in X?

Tags: x11, fonts, gtk

Bitmap fonts can be enabled by adding a `70-yes-bitmaps.conf` to the X configuration.  However, this enables **all** available bitmap fonts.  Is it possible to enable bitmap fonts selectively; for example, only fonts in a certain directory?  I am using GTK, in case it makes a difference.